# Constructor parameter matching in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have classes which can be serialized by both Json.NET and protobuf-net for various reasons.
Both serializers support deserialization via the "empty constructor and property setting" routine, which is how I use them today.

My issue is that this deserialization technique requires having an object in a limbo state - right after its empty constructor was called and before the properties were set. This is problematic because it's harder to reason about object state, and a quick way to notice this issue is with nullable reference type warnings, where the compiler can't figure out that a property is actually not null (even though I know it's filled after deserialization).

A nice solution for this in the JSON world is to annotate a constructor with the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute, and having the deserializer match the properties with the constructor parameters. For example:

```
public string Prop { get; }

[JsonConstructor]
public Obj(string prop)
{
    Prop = prop;
}
```

This way, I can make sure that the object was initialized correctly, it's never in a limbo state, and I can reason about its properties.

Is there a similar method for protobuf-net? I've seen the `UseConstructor = false` option, but that's not a complete solution because it doesn't produce the object in one step.

Comment: What about making the default constructor `private` and the properties `get; init;`? This basically gives you the best of both worlds (assuming the reflection code is willing to call a private constructor, but it arguably should be). The "limbo state" then still exists, but only the deserializers are exposed to it, and they're expected to handle it. For nullability specifically you'll also want to wrap that constructor with a `#nullable disable / restore`.

Comment: The only scenario where this wouldn't work is if properties have complicated interdependencies where setters must be called in a specific order for the final state to be correct, but if that's the case you have no real choice other than to use a constructor anyway (or a custom builder), and such things arguably have no place in a type used for serialization -- serializing a custom memento class instead is much easier to understand and version in that case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's a good suggestion. Not bullet proof as you said, but definitely a good compromise. That is, until protobuf-net supports other construction techniques...